# How do I do two operations per one ternary option in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

There is a condition, which is also a ternary option

```
?spotify.search({type:'track',query:`${d}`},(e2,d2)=>!!e2
```

So if there is an error or if there is no error it goes to

```
 ?console.log(e2)
 :console.log(`Artist ${d2.tracks.items[0].artists[0].name}, album ${d2.tracks.items[0].album.name}, song ${d2.tracks.items[0].name}, preview url ${d2.tracks.items[0].preview_url}`))
```

However I want to do more than console.log for the second option.. I also want to append a log text file without losing data from the callback function. Is there any way to do both console.log and the line below for one ternary option?

```
require(`fs`).appendFile(`log.txt`,`Artist ${d2.tracks.items[0].artists[0].name}, album ${d2.tracks.items[0].album.name}, song ${d2.tracks.items[0].name}, preview url ${d2.tracks.items[0].preview_url}`,`utf8`,e=>e?console.log(e):true)
```

Here it is recognizing it as undefined

```
(e2,d2)=>!!e2
        ?console.log(e2)
        :(console.log(`Artist ${d2.tracks.items[0].artists[0].name}, album ${d2.tracks.items[0].album.name}, song ${d2.tracks.items[0].name}, preview url ${d2.tracks.items[0].preview_url}`)),
         require(`fs`).appendFile(`log.txt`,`Artist ${d2.tracks.items[0].artists[0].name}, album ${d2.tracks.items[0].album.name}, song ${d2.tracks.items[0].name}, preview url ${d2.tracks.items[0].preview_url}`,`utf8`,e3=>e3?console.log(e3):true))
```

Comment: Sure but for readability might be better to use `if/else` instead or use a function call

Answer (score 2):

You can use the comma operator, which evaluates a comma-separated list of expressions and returns the value of the last expression:

```
? console.log(e2)
: (
   console.log(`Artist ${d2.tracks.items[0].artists[0].name}, album ${d2.tracks.items[0].album.name}, song ${d2.tracks.items[0].name}, preview url ${d2.tracks.items[0].preview_url}`)),
   require(`fs`).appendFile(`log.txt`,`Artist ${d2.tracks.items[0].artists[0].name}, album ${d2.tracks.items[0].album.name}, song ${d2.tracks.items[0].name}, preview url ${d2.tracks.items[0].preview_url}`,`utf8`,e=>e?console.log(e):true)
);
```

But I wouldn't recommend it, it's not very readable. The conditional operator should probably only be used when you need to use the resulting expression - otherwise, use `if`/`else`.

Comment: I heard from a more experienced peer that nowadays it's considered to signal low level of knowledge if somebody uses the actual word of function instead of an arrow function and if/else instead of ternaries. Is this true?

Comment: Definitely not. A full-fledged `function` can be necessary (or useful) when you're looking for the proper `this` context. Using the conditional operator when you don't need the expression is a code smell, *not* a benefit. Sure, it works, but it's hard to read and requires the comma operator (which should almost never be used) - best to do it only when golfing.

Comment: Hey I did what you suggested, but it didn't work. It recognized d2 from the callback function as undefined in the second expression

Comment: I just edited my question it shows below what it's recognizing as undefined, the d2 to be exact... data passed by the callback function from the api...

Comment: even though its within the same ternary option

Comment: Sounds like the function was not called with a second parameter (or the second parameter is `undefined`). (start debugging by just doing `console.log(d2)` instead of the big complicated conditional)

Comment: Hey my bad, i just fixed it, it was missing a paren, now it's working like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: @OlegArsyonov: There is a school of programming that tries to minimize side effects and shunt them off to the edges of the system.  When working that way, one will often prefer expressions to statements and so prefer ternaries to `if`-`else`s.  Code focused on side-effects should not worry about this.  Students of that school may see themselves  as operating at a higher level.  After all, they're well versed in key algorithmic techniques such as [recursion and condescension](http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2009/05/brief-incomplete-and-mostly-wrong.html)!